# Getting a List of Odd/Even Numbers Using Stream

Tags: java

The goal is to print `[2,4]` and successfully create a list of odd/even numbers. My syntax is probably just way off or slightly off.

```
Stream<Integer> s = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
s.filter(p -> p % 2 == 0)
 .collect(Collectors.toList())
 .forEach(e -> System.out.print(e + " "));

System.out.println();
System.out.println(s.toString());
```

Results...

```
2 4 
java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@682a0b20
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check out the [ask] and [tour] links to see how to ask questions, how to best use the site and what the site is for, and then consider [edit]ing and improving your question.  In particular, consider making your question more clear, focused, and understandable, especially with code posted as text, since doing this can help improve the question greatly, can improve its chances of getting a decent answer soon, and can reduce its chances of being closed, down-voted or deleted. Best of luck!

Comment: “goal is to print [2,4] and successfully create a list of odd/even numbers.”  Which is it?  Is your goal to print [2,4] (which clearly is just even numbers), or is your goal to print both odd and even numbers in some manner?

Answer (score 1):

You can't print a Stream directly. Even if you could, this one is already consumed by the [terminal operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps). Just scrap the `forEach()` (or convert it to a `peek()` if you really need it), and print the result of your `collect()` call:

```
List<Integer> result = s.filter(p -> p % 2 == 0)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: shmosel's answer worked thanks